# ShieldUI Grid row count

Tags: shieldui

In ShieldUI (1.7.13) Grid
How can I have a row count beside each record in a grid?

This is not data from the JSON which provides the other data for the Grid.

Situation, I am scrolling a list of hundreds of records and want to provide the consumer of the data the row number of the various rows in the grid.

Similar to the row number in any popular spreadsheet application (Excel, Google Sheets, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new column as the first one, specifying a custom columnTemplate for it. In there you can show the current index of each row.

More information is available here:
https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/columns/columnTemplate